# Replacing multiple values by a single value in a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am searching if values from list 1 are available in list2 or not. if whatever values from list 1 are found in `list2` then I want to replace all those values in `list2` by a single value.

```
list1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'cat', 'peacock']
list2 = ['hello', 'apple', 'cat', 'sherrif']
```

Solution I tried:

```
for i,item in enumerate(list2):
  if item in list1:
    list2[i]= 'cat'

print(list2)
```

Current output:
replaced every value in `list2` by `jackie`

`list2 = ['hello', 'jackie', 'jackie', 'sherrif']`

Expected: Output: As values like apple, cat from `list1` are available in `list2` so in output, both should be replaced by single value `jackie`. if no value found `list1` found in `list2` then list2 remains same

```
list2 = ['hello', 'jackie', 'sherrif']
```

Comment: Unclear. What happens if `list2=['banana', 'apple',  'peacock', 'cat']` ? Do you replace it with `['banana', 'jackie',  'peacock', 'jackie']` or `['banana', 'jackie',  'peacock']`? In other words, do you replace only the first value that is also contained in `list1` and remove all the reset, or do you replace each consecutive sequence of values also contained in `list1` with a separate `"jackie"`?

Comment: do you want the order of the list to be maintained?

Comment: Note that `item in list1` is O(len(list1)) since it searches all elements of `list1`. The total algorithm becomes O(len(list1)*len(list2)), which is OK if either one of the lists are small, but becomes a disaster if both lists are big. Solution: create `set1=set(list1)` and work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Changed = False
for x in list1:
    if x in list2:
        if not Changed:
            list2[list2.index(x)] = "jackie"
            Changed = True
        else:
            list2.remove(x)
```

Comment: O(n ** 2) complexity. OK for very small list (<10), very bad for big lists (>1000)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a list comprehension and a little 'trick' to remove duplicates:

```
print(list(dict.fromkeys(['Jacky' if el in list1 else el for el in list2])))
```

The list comprehension should be clear: Add 'Jacky' if the element in list2 occurs in list1, else add the element itself.

Then we create a dictionary using the list items as keys. This automatically deletes duplicates, and finally we convert it back to a list:

```
['hello', 'Jacky', 'sherrif']
```

**Following the comments below:**

*IF* it is mandatory that duplicates in list2 are preserved *AND* the order is important and you don't want to or cannot rely on the order in a dictionary, use this instead:

```
list3 = []
[list3.append(el) for el in ['Jacky' if el in list1 else el for el in list2] if el!='Jacky' or 'Jacky' not in list3]
print(list3)
```

Comment: In this answer: 1. The order is not guaranteed to be preserved. 2. It loses duplicates, which are perfectly legal, and should be maintained if they are not also contained in `list1`.

Comment: First: I believe the order is guaranteed because nowadays dictionaries preserve the order in which keys are added. Second: you're right ;-) though the OP was not specific about that case.

Comment: you are correct only as of python-3.7. For python-3.6, or earlier, there is no guarantee regarding the iteration order of dict elements

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small function that does what you want and returns at the end both lists. It checks whether any element of `list_1` is present in the `list_2` if it is true, the whole `list_2` is changed by the list comprehension into a list containing the word `Jackie`

```
list1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'cat', 'peacock']
list2 = ['hello', 'apple', 'cat', 'sherrif']

def low_func(list_1, list_2):
    for i in list_1:
        if i in list_2:
            list2 = ['jackie' for x in list_2]
    return list1, list2
```